# Deconstruct a pattern in a definition

Tags: isabelle

Given we have a

```
datatype 'a foo = Foo 'a
```

I'd like to make a definition where I have the `Foo a` deconstructed available, so I can access the `a`. I'd like to write

```
definition do_foo :: "'a foo ⇒ 'a" where
  "do_foo (Foo a) ≡ if True then a else a"
```

In Isabelle2021, I get the following error: `Bad arguments on lhs: "Foo a"`.

What is the *nicest* way to achieve what I want to achieve?

---

I see the following solutions, but all of them do not look *nice* to me.

### Deconstruction via `case` on the rhs

```
definition do_foo :: "'a foo ⇒ 'a" where
  "do_foo fooa ≡ case fooa of Foo a  ⇒ if True then a else a"
```

Not nice because of the verbose `case`.

### Adding a getter to the datatype

```
datatype 'a foo = Foo (a: 'a)

definition do_foo :: "'a foo ⇒ 'a" where
  "do_foo fooa ≡ if True then a fooa else a fooa"
```

Not nice because the getter `a` pollutes the namespace and `a fooa` does not look very nice.

### `fun` instead of `definition` (not working)

```
fun do_foo :: "'a foo ⇒ 'a" where
  "do_foo (Foo a) ≡ if True then a else a"
```

produces error `Not an equation` because of the `≡` which seems not to be allowed in a `fun`.

### `fun` instead of `definition` (working)

```
fun do_foo :: "'a foo ⇒ 'a" where
  "do_foo (Foo a) = (if True then a else a)"
```

Not nice because I need parenthesis around the `if` statement and in order to mimic the definition character (i.e, the definition does not get auto-unfolded in a proof), I need to add things such as `declare do_foo.simps[simp del]`.

Comment: You mean `declare do_foo.simps[simp del]` right?

Comment: From my understanding, the fact that `≡` works is more an accident than an intended feature. So I think `fun` is the best way.

Comment: Yet another alternative involves the use of `function` (instead of `fun`) and conditional equations, e.g. `function do_foo :: "nat foo ⇒ nat" where  "do_foo (Foo a) = a" if "a > 0" | "do_foo (Foo a) = Suc a" if "¬a > 0" ...`. The drawback is the need to discharge the proof obligations about completeness and compatibility of patterns, plus a termination proof.